# Widget won't work due to old JavaScript? Any ideas how to make it work?

Tags: jquery, widgets, ajax, javascript

I was trying to add this widget to my [blog](http://sparkandbark.com/)

```
<!--BEGIN PROFILE WIDGET-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" 
            type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://lookbook.nu/widget/profile.js?id=2303472&width=standard&align=center&fanbox=yes&hash=14575a9cd02fd36d2758e5db3cb92b5a"></script>
<div id="profile_widget_container_2303472"></div>
<!--END PROFILE WIDGET-->
```

But it messes with my design because the first JavaScript is too old. When I remove it, the widget won't load. They (Lookbook) don't have new widgets, only the ones with the old code. Is there any plugin I could install to my WordPress blog to make it work though? Any coding I could add?

Any help is very apppreciated :)

Comment: sorry, but question that are about local bugs without sharing the code, and about integration with 3rd party services are off-topic here

Comment: Like MarkKaplun said, it's off topic. You will have to rely their documentation and code. Unfortunately the answer given by @bravokeyl below is not valid either given that the error supplied is only a 404 of one file unsupplied. There are two other failing errors we can't see.

Comment: @NathanPowell the other two errors are from Instagram api since i'm on Office network and Instagram is blocked (that's why those other two errors). I agree with you about this topic being off-topic. Just pointed a 404 error.

Comment: I surely doubt simple double quotes are the problem here, seeing the characters transfer easily to his question's code. Nice to note the other errors. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
From your site i can say that script is not being loaded because of
wrong opening quote for script tag.Use **`"`** instead of **`”`**

So

```
<script src=”http://lookbook.nu/widget/profile.js?id=2303472&width=standard&align=left&stats_fans=1&fanbox=yes&hash=14575a9cd02fd36d2758e5db3cb92b5a”></script>
```

Should be this

```
<script src="http://lookbook.nu/widget/profile.js?id=2303472&width=standard&align=left&stats_fans=1&fanbox=yes&hash=14575a9cd02fd36d2758e5db3cb92b5a"></script>
```

**Update:**

Add `<script> $LB = jQuery; </script>` 
before the other script tag. I mean before

```
<script src="http://lookbook.nu/widget/profile.js?id=2303472&width=standard&align=left&stats_fans=1&fanbox=yes&hash=14575a9cd02fd36d2758e5db3cb92b5a"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I added your version without the mistake but it still doesn't work. I also read that other people have had this problem before. Is there any way to make it load?

Comment: It's not working because of the jQuery conflict.

Comment: @MalinRouge check the updated answer now, hopefully it should work

Comment: Oh my god! You did it! Thank you so much :) I had to try different versions though, it only works with the div classes right behind. So this is the working code:

 <script> $LB = jQuery; type="text/javascript" </script> <script src=" http://lookbook.nu/widget/profile.js?id=2303472&width=standard&align=center&fanbox=yes&hash=14575a9cd02fd36d2758e5db3cb92b5a"></script><div id="profile_widget_container_2303472"></div>